# How to refine prisma type

Tags: typescript, prisma

This is a very simplified case, I have more advanced cases. I have defined a "payment" model in my schema like this:

```
model Payment {
  id                      Int      @default(autoincrement()) @id
  covered                 Boolean?
  paid                    Boolean
  amount                  number
}
```

Doing `const payments = Payment.findMany` with all properties selected, this gives us a type of this:

```
type Payment = {
  id: number;
  covered?: boolean;
  paid: boolean;
  amount: number;
}
```

However I want to tell Prisma that `findMany` should actually return this below. In below, covered is non-null in case of `paid` being `true`:

```
type Payment = {
  id: number;
  amount: number;
} & (
  | { paid: false; covered?: never }
  | { paid: true; covered: boolean }
)
```

Is it possible to tell Prisma this refined type hint somehow? I tried this in the code below:

```
const payments = await prisma.payment.findMany(.....) as Omit<typeof payments[number], 'paid' | 'covered'> & (
  | { paid: false; covered?: never }
  | { paid: true; covered: boolean }
);
```

Comment: Why can't `covered` by default be false? What is the difference in meaning between `false` and `null` for `covered`?

Comment: I think you're over-engineering your type declarations while your requirement at-hand can easily be expressed thru code and code comment

Comment: This is a very simplified case, I have more advanced cases. But "covered" doesn't make sense until it's paid. @hhearts

Comment: One example is refining JSON type. @TrashCan

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use what's called "discriminant type" using a common property, in your case `paid` property like this. Here's the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QApwJ4C2E4yA3gFDLLAAmAXMiAK4EBG0A3JcgA5y0NWAeyEAbCHBBcqcAkKbgGzNp3IBfcuVCRYiFLlq5CxMMggAPSCBoY0mHPiIkKVPgORgoTCNOQIhAG7QEPTIwmISUuqa2tDwSMgAqiBuNEZOphZWNnZY6SZk3KkM8KJYXBrk-iAYpqn5isgGaY4FALyFVO4AjAA03LLyjd0ADP1U-kFQIQye3uO8-KFzEOpcVUI1pgr1rY3Ju8YkHS7UoX0DcgpgDKMLk8HLXhC9yAD0b8gAKgAWwLYAd02AHJTP4CDxgOIwhAEHAmFgPHgeCgAAYHJYNMCo5A0IQQDAgUHIH5wILIVEPaY0VFFJYlOBlVZqDhAA) to the playground for your reference

```
interface BasePayment {
  id: number;
  paid: boolean;
  amount: number;
}

interface PaidPayment extends BasePayment {
  paid: true;
  covered: boolean;
}

interface UnpaidPayment extends BasePayment {
  paid: false;
}

const paidPayment: PaidPayment = {
  id: 1,
  amount: 10,
  covered: true,
  paid: true
};

const unpaidPayment: UnpaidPayment = {
  id: 1,
  amount: 10,
  covered: true, // This won't compile because type `UnpaidPayment` doesn't have `covered`
  paid: false
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was doing this, but I was having to cast `prisma.findMany` and other prisma method results `as unknown as MySpecificType` :( I was hoping I could get prisma to do this, as when I go `as unknown` I lose all type safety and am now telling it everything, not just the limited parts I wanted to refine.

Comment: You can use declaration merging to patch prisma's existing declarations